# Haskell type declarations for multiple parameter functions

Tags: haskell

I'm looking through [this](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html) introduction to Haskell which contains this example:

```
data Tree a             = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

which it says is essentially also defining the types:

```
Branch                  :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
Leaf                    :: a -> Tree a
```

I understand the Leaf definition is saying that it maps an `a` to a `Tree` of `a`. but I don't understand the Branch definition, I read it as "Branch maps `Tree` of `a` to `Tree` of `a` to `Tree` of `a` which doesn't sound correct. Is this because all Haskell functions get curried by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read it as "Branch maps Tree of a to Tree of a to Tree of a"

You can think of the definition as a function that takes a `Tree a` and returns another function, which also takes a `Tree a` and produces a `Tree a` (which is the final result, a tree with two branches). Your signature of `Branch` is equivalent to

```
Branch :: Tree a -> (Tree a -> Tree a)
```

The notion that every function has just one input parameter is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 5):

No. If it had a signature like:

```
Branch :: (Tree a, Tree a) -> Tree a
```

then you should have to feed it a tuple, and call the constructor like:

```
Branch (tree1,tree2)
```

`Branch` has however a signature:

```
Branch :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

Or with explicit parenthesis:

```
Branch :: Tree a -> (Tree a -> Tree a)
```

So when you feed `Branch` a first parameter, like `Branch tree1`, the signature is:

```
(Branch t1) :: Tree a -> Tree a
```

when you finally feed it a second parameter `t2`, its type will collapse to:

```
((Branch t1) t2) :: Tree a
```

---

A more convenient example is for instance `(+)` which is not a constructor, but a function. `(+)` **our** plus `(+)` has signature

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

(Haskells plus is a bit more generic, but let's not consider this now).

If you now write `(5+)` you have specialized your function to a function:

```
(5+) :: Int -> Int
```

In other words you constructed a *new* function that will add `5` to the given number.

---

Since the signatures for `(a,b) -> c` and `a -> b -> c` are however a bit equivalent, Haskell provides the [`curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:curry) and [`uncurry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) functions:

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

If you decide you need for instance an additional constructor for `Branch` that should be fed a tuple, you can construct such constructor:

```
branchTuple :: (Tree a, Tree a) -> Tree a
branchTuple = uncurry Branch
```

Answer (score 2):

`Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)` is a constructor with two type parameters, both of which are `Tree a`, and the result of that constructor is a `Tree a`, hence the definition of

```haskell
Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

> I understand the Leaf definition is saying that it maps an a to a Tree of a. but I dont understand the Branch definition, shouldn't it be something like:
>
> ```haskell
> Branch :: (Tree a, Tree a) -> Tree a
> ```

No, because if you used `(Tree a, Tree a)`, you would be defining a single type parameter which is a tuple.

Comment: There is a single _type_ parameter in both cases: `a`.